# Preventing this foreach loop from stopping early

Tags: c#, foreach, attask

Last week I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572684/why-is-this-foreach-loop-stopping-early/31572749#31572749) question, which was given the answer that the AtTask API does have a set limit, and to change this, "$$LIMIT" needs to be used, as explained by the [AtTask site](https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/#Limits).

This is very helpful except that I am unsure where to put "$$LIMIT", as I am using C# and the AtTask C# example does not include this. I have been scouring the AtTask developer site for a solution and have been coming up empty handed.

How do I use this code in C# to raise the call limit?

Edit

The code sample included in my previous question:

```
JToken projects = client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, new {groupID = userGroupID});
foreach (var j in projects["data"].Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine("# " + counter + " Name: {0}", j.Value<string>("name")); 
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post us some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like their API turns the object passed to the second parameter of Search() into query string parameters.  So in your example

```
client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, new {groupID = userGroupID});
```

The following url is created (123 represents whatever your group id is).

```
GET /attask/api/project/search?groupID=123
```

So to add $$LIMIT to the url add $$LIMIT to the object.  Unfortunately, C# doesn't allow $ in names.  So my suggestion is to modify their C# API slightly.  First change your call to Search() to this

```
client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, new {groupID = userGroupID, __Limit = 200 });
```

Then, in AtTaskRestClient.cs, change parameterObjectToStringArray() at the end of the file to the following.

```
private string[] parameterObjectToStringArray(object parameters, params string[] toAdd) {
    var properties = parameters.GetType().GetProperties();
    List<string> p = new List<string>(properties.Length);
    p.AddRange(toAdd);
    foreach(var prop in properties) {
        string propName = prop.Name;
        if (propName.StartsWith("__"))
        {
            propName = "$$" + propName.Substring(2);
        }
        string line = string.Format("{0}={1}", propName, prop.GetValue(parameters, null));
        p.Add(line);
    }
    return p.ToArray();
}
```

This change will also let you use their other parameters that start with $$ like $$FIRST.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste mistake.  I fixed the code example.

Comment: This looks like a very good idea, but I am still only pulling 100 results with this.

Comment: Correction, you're a genius.  After tinkering with that code for a bit, the only thing that needs changed is "__Limit" needs to be all caps. Much appreciation!